# Result by model

Tags: cakephp-3.x

I have this query:

```
$data = TableRegistry::get('Dogs');
$data = $data->find('all')
    ->contain(['Foods'])
    ->select(['name','breed','sex','Foods.name','Foods.quality'])
    ->last()
    ->toArray();
```

It returns this result:

```
[
    'name' => 'Dug',
    'breed' => 'Golden Retriever',
    'sex' => 'Male',
    'food' => [
        'name' => 'Best Food',
        'quality' => 'A+'
     ]
]
```

I want to know if there is any way to make CakePHP return the result as:

```
[
    'dog' => [
        'name' => 'Dug',
        'breed' => 'Golden Retriever',
        'sex' => 'Male'
    ],
    'food' => [
        'name' => 'Best Food',
        'quality' => 'A+'
     ]
]
```

How would I do this? I am pretty sure it's very simple, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So following Salines' post, I decided to just build something quick and easy to work with since the content is a bit more dynamic than the example I posted.

```
$data = TableRegistry::get($this->table);
$data = $data->find()
    ->contain($associated)
    ->select($this->data_fields)
    ->last()
    ->toArray();
$main = strtolower(Inflector::singularize($this->table));
$data[$main] = [];
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if(!is_array($value)) {
        $data[$main][$key] = $value;
        unset($data[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
$data => [
    'dog' => [
        'name' => $dog->name,
        'breed' => $dog->breed,
        'sex' => $dog->sex
        ],
    'food' => $dog->foods
];
$this->set('data', $data);
```

Comment: perhaps it's a solution but not very clean. Will look into it some more